# Increase daily quora for custom searches

Tags: google-custom-search, google-cloud-platform

I have reached daily limit for Google custom search api. Is there way that I can increase the limit over 10,000 requests per day?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get higher than 10,000 search queries would be to upgrade to [Site Search](https://www.google.com/work/search/products/gss.html) which allows a higher quota.

Comment: Can I still use api to call after upgrade?

Comment: It says Up to 50000 queries per year for $250. This is even lower than 10k/day custom search queries.

Comment: I don't get it. Now, I can have 10k/day queries on Google CSE. This is 10k/day * 365 = 3,650,000 queries and it is much more than the plan you just showed me. The 2nd highest site search plan is 500k queries/year for $2000.